# Where is usr/local?

Tags: 13.04, python, directory

I ran the following code in a terminal:

```
python -c "                 
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
import django
print(django.__path__)"
```

This returns the following path:

['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django']

but I simply cannot find usr/local (from the GUI). Where should it be?

I'm not sure what other information would help, please let me know!

Comment: /usr/local *is* a location.

Comment: @psusi I'm pretty sure OP knows it's a location, but apparently he's not familiar with `nautilus`, which starts you in your home folder, and you need to go up form it to the root directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type

```
sudo cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

in to terminal. That should take you to the folder

The usr folder is part of the file system, it is accessed from the root of your file system

Comment: Sorry, I meant is there a way to access it from the GUI?

Comment: Type `sudo nautilus` in to teminal, this gives you access to root folders

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to be of assistance. :D

Comment: You do not need to sudo to cd to /usr/local though you would not be able to edit the files. You do need root privileges for editing but the files are visible as a reugular user.

Comment: @Colton You can view it in Nautilus but you may have to select to show hidden files (Ctrl-H). You do not need to launch Nautilus with sudo (it's actually discouraged to use Sudo for a graphical program) to just view the files. If you need to edit an individual file in nautilus, the right click and select open as administrator. If you need to move system/hidden files in Nautilus, then you should open Nautilus with GKSU (not Sudo), move what you have too and then close it so that you don't unintentionally alter something else while opened as root.

Comment: This (accepted) answer here makes absolutely no sense. `sudo cd` will not even *work*, since `cd` is a bash built-in and not an executable. Even *if* that worked, it would make no sense to use it to get to the wanted location since this location is accessible for everybody anyway. Even if `sudo cd` worked *and* this location was *not* accessible for everybody, it *still* wouldn't make sense to do that because afterwards you still wouldn't be able to do anything in that folder---not even read its contents.

Answer (score 15):

**Where should it be?** By default when you open the file manager you run around your home directory(`/home/username`), same as in windows `C:\Users\Username` . Notice how `/usr/local` starts with backslash ? There's root directory from which you can access other directories; the image to keep in mind is the root directory is where root starts, and everything else is branching form it

**How to access the folder you need:**

Method #1 : press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> in the file manager ( which is called nautilus, by the way) and type `/usr/local` into the address bar or `/` .

Method#2: Pressing repeatedly <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> buttown in file manager will get you to root directory (which is like C:\ folder in windows), and navigate graphically to whatever folder you need from there.

Method #3: Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to open "Run command" dialogue and type `nautilus /usr/local`

Answer (score 7):

```
cd /usr/local
```

will get you there

You do need root privileges to edit files there, in which case you can invoke `sudo`, be very cautious about meddling with files however in the /usr directory and in the root directory `/` in general.

BTW don't be afraid of the command line! A useful introduction to the CLI is available [here](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php).